# auto with ternary operator and nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-operator, auto

Can I use `auto` with such usage of the ternary operator?

```cpp
auto obj = some_cond ? static_cast<className*>(baseClassObj) : nullptr;
```

It compiles in Visual Studio, and the code works OK, but can there be any unexpected side effects? Or, will `auto` here always be `className*` and I can relax and write such code? Or, with the ternary operator, is it better to write this?

```cpp
className* obj = some_cond ? static_cast<className*>(baseClassObj) : nullptr;
```

Comment: The type of every C++ variable is determined at compile time.  The type of your `auto obj` is `className*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto` deduces to the type of the value that is assigned to it.  The ternary operator can only return one type.  `nullptr` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, but no pointer type is implicitly convertible to `std::nullptr_t`, so in this example the ternary operator must always return `className*`, and thus `auto` will always deduce as `className*`.